# How I can access data property from MySQL in Controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I learning about laravel framework, I don't know how to access property in my controller.

```
public function uuid(Request $request)
{
    if($request->get('uuid') == null) return abort(404);
    $uuid = $request->get('uuid');
    $users = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('uuid', $uuid)->get();

    $result = array([
        'id' => $users['id'],
        'username' => $users['username'],
        'uuid' => $users['uuid'],
    ]);

    return view ('dashboard')->with('username', $result['username']);
}
```

in my dashboard.blade.php

`{{$username}}`

When i come to dashboard it show error like this

ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Undefined index: username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **First()** instead of **get()** you'll get object so access data like.

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('uuid', $uuid)->first();

$result = array([
    'id' => $users->id,
    'username' => $users->username,
    'uuid' => $users->uuid,
]);

return view ('dashboard')->with('username', $result['username']);
```

Now sort way to do it.

```
 $user = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('uuid', $uuid)->first();
 $username = '';
 if(!empty($user)){
    $username = $user->username 
 }

return view ('dashboard',compact('username'));
```

Comment: Glad to helped.

Answer (score 0):

`$users` is a collection of users. So you cannot access a property of a user like `$users['id']`;

If you want to get one user object from the database, you need to call `first()` instead of `get()`

**Possible Solution**

```php
$user = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('uuid', $uuid)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use firstOrFail();

```
 $users = DB::table('users')->select('*')->where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();

$result = array([
    'id' => $users->id,
    'username' => $users->username,
    'uuid' => $users->uuid,
]);

return view ('dashboard')->with('username', compact('username'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible short version of your solution may be like following

```
public function uuid(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::select('username')->where('uuid', $request->uuid)->firstOrFail();

    return view ('dashboard')->with('username', $user->username);
}
```